# JavaFX Hide ScrollPane gray border

Tags: java, javafx-2, javafx

Is there any way of hiding the gray border of an ScrollPane control in JavaFX ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17540428/1725096

Answer (score 47, accepted):

All controls in JavaFX can be modified using CSS styling. You may want to take a look at [reference](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/javafx/javafx/1.3/docs/api/javafx.scene/doc-files/cssref.html#region) or [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/css_tutorial/jfxpub-css_tutorial.htm).

Gray ScrollPane's border is actually the only part of the background which is visible behind the content. So you can change it by modifying the background:

```
    ScrollPane sp = new ScrollPane();
    sp.setStyle("-fx-background-color:transparent;");
```

Comment: Thanks, I just used this to hide the border of a TextArea also.  Looks like it works on quite a few components.

Comment: Yep, border-only visible background is a common approach

Answer (score 12):

Or in CSS

```
.scroll-pane {
    -fx-background-color:transparent;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Making the border transparent will leave a 1 pixel gap around the edge. IMHO, the correct answer is the one that Jens Piegsa linked to.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/17540428/1725096

Answer (score 5):

In pure Java, without CSS, you need to set the background like this, which is a lot more verbose than the CSS approach.

```
ScrollPane scrollPane = new ScrollPane();
scrollPane.setBackground(
  new Background(new BackgroundFill(Color.TRANSPARENT, null, null))
);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to blow away any pre-defined styles applied you can use:

```
ScrollPane scrollPane = new ScrollPane();    
scrollPane.getStyleClass().clear();
```

This also works for any sub-type of Node