# JavaFX ScrollPane border and background

Tags: javafx-2, scrollpane

I'm having some problem regarding the default background and border of the ScrollPane.
Using this style made the problem clearer to see.

```
setStyle("-fx-background-color:blue; -fx-border-color:crimson;");
```

[image: Image show the background and the border]

I've tried this style and got no luck only the red border gone and left me with the blue one.

```
setStyle("-fx-background-color:blue; -fx-background-insets:0; -fx-border-color:crimson; -fx-border-width:0; -fx-border-insets:0;");
```

[image: Image show the background and the border after my best work around]

I've looked at this old post [JavaFX Hide ScrollPane gray border](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12899788/javafx-hide-scrollpane-gray-border) and http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/ui_controls/editor.htm

This line of code doesn't work neither

```
scrollPane.getStyleClass().add("noborder-scroll-pane");
```

Thanks

Comment: In JavaFX 8 with the new default theme, ScrollPane background colors can be difficult to set.  For those cases, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22952531/scrollpanes-in-javafx-8-always-have-gray-background

Answer (score 32):

In the current version of JavaFX 8, you can use the edge-to-edge style class to remove the border entirely:

```
<ScrollPane styleClass="edge-to-edge"/>
```

Comment: Very nice find.  It is not documented in the [JavaFX CSS reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#scrollpane), but it is part of the default `modena.css` stylesheet for JavaFX 8.

Answer (score 23):

I have found a solution and would liked to post it here so others won't need to waste their time find it again.

By looking at the default css of JavaFx (caspian.css) which has been extracted from the library using this command.

```
jar xf jfxrt.jar com/sun/javafx/scene/control/skin/caspian/caspian.css
```

I could see that the one I missed is

```
-fx-padding: 0;
```

So this is the css class I'm using.

```
.scroll-pane {
    -fx-background-insets: 0;
    -fx-padding: 0;
}

.scroll-pane:focused {
    -fx-background-insets: 0;
}

.scroll-pane .corner {
    -fx-background-insets: 0;
}
```

Comment: Was trying the "-fx-background-color: transparent" but the "border" was still annoying me, so I found your answer. Thank you sir! :)

Answer (score 11):

Try use this first

```
.scroll-pane > .viewport {
   -fx-background-color: transparent;
}
```

Before setting the background color

Comment: While the higher voted solutions didn't work for me, this one did!

Answer (score 9):

There seems to be a simple solution, which is to use "-fx-background: rgb(80,80,80);", that is,

```
scrollPane.setStyle("-fx-background: rgb(80,80,80);");
```

At least this works perfectly for me, while "-fx-background-color: rgb(80,80,80);" or "-fx-control-inner-background: rgb(80,80,80);" do not work in javafx 8. "-fx-background-color: rgb(80,80,80);" did work in earlier versions of javafx.

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
-fx-background-color: transparent;
-fx-control-inner-background: transparent;
```

If you set only `-fx-background-color`, you will see the color change is applied to only the ScrollPane's inner edges, and the color of the center area is still not changed.

The `-fx-control-inner-background` property will change the color of that center area.

Answer (score 2):

Honestly, your question was not clear enough, but I am only providing this answer to help others if I can.

What is causing this problem is you have the **ScrollPane** and inside it something called **viewport** that is bound to the **ScrollPane**. The properties that you apply for the **ScrollPane** object does not apply for the **viewport**. If you want to apply the properties for both *ONLY*, not the children too, you have to use the **stylesheet** property, not the **style** property itself, which uses in-line css code. For example, if you want to make the **ScrollPane** transparent, you have to apply the property for both, assuming the name of file is "scrollPane.css", like so:

```css
#mainScrollPane > .viewport {
    -fx-background-color: transparent;
}

#mainScrollPane {
    -fx-background-color: transparent;
}
```

However, you need to apply a special Id property for the **ScrollPane** object, so it does not apply for the children:

```java
  ScrollPane scrollPane = new ScrollPane(root);
  scrollPane.setId("mainScrollPane");
  scrollPane.getStyleSheets().add("scrollPane.css");
```

Comment: I can confirm this is working with transparent color, while other answers can only set an opaque color because they are changing the `ScrollPane` style.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than use FXML or CSS I prefer to consume the event, but this only works on the portion that has content.  If your scrollPane is larger than its content you also have to fill the remaining space.

```
scrollPane.getContent().setOnMousePressed(Event::consume);
scrollPane.setFitToHeight(true);
scrollPane.setFitToWidth(true);
```