# JavaFx: combobox max width

Tags: java, javafx

I want to do: fixed column, liquid column(50%), fixed column, liquid column(50%) in GridPane. And I have the following FXML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.60-ea" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <children>
      <GridPane layoutX="100.0" layoutY="74.0" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
        <columnConstraints>
          <ColumnConstraints hgrow="NEVER" maxWidth="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefWidth="100.0" />
            <ColumnConstraints hgrow="ALWAYS" />
            <ColumnConstraints hgrow="NEVER" maxWidth="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefWidth="100.0" />
          <ColumnConstraints hgrow="ALWAYS" />
        </columnConstraints>
        <rowConstraints>
          <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
          <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
          <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
        </rowConstraints>
         <children>
            <ComboBox maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" GridPane.columnIndex="3" GridPane.hgrow="ALWAYS" />
            <Label text="Label" GridPane.columnIndex="2" />
            <TextField GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.hgrow="SOMETIMES" />
            <Label text="Label" />
            <Label text="Label" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
            <TextField maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
            <Label text="Label" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
            <ComboBox maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" GridPane.columnIndex="3" GridPane.hgrow="ALWAYS" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
         </children>
      </GridPane>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

However, when I focus comboboxes they change their size. For example I start preview in SB:
[image]
And now I press arrow on comboboxes:
[image]
As you see all layout changed. How to fix it?

Comment: Can you remove GridPane.hgrow="ALWAYS" from comboboxes and try again?

Comment: @Uluk Biy The result is the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the min/pref width settings on the grid column with the combo boxes. You set the min and pref size to something reasonable and keep maxSize the same.

[image]

This prevents the combo boxes from deciding they need a larger size and still keeps the "liquid column" functionality.

Comment: I really don't know, my best guess is that the drop down list wanted more space and since `USE_COMPUTED_SIZE` allowed it to choose its own best size, it gave itself a larger size.

Comment: I see that JavaFx beast is really very angry :) If you have a minute, could you take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30736521/javafx8-is-table-cellfocused-ignored

Comment: Hoever, this solution doesn't provide 50% to 50%. It's about 47% to 53%

Comment: Just change the pref width of the TextField column to match the ComboBox column. That should be around 200.

Comment: Yes, I did it. 50% to 50%