# JavaFX ScrollPane how set transparent background

Tags: java, css, javafx, scenebuilder

I can not set transparent background in `scrollpane`. Probably because it contains `anchorpane`, and that `anchorpane` contains buttons? White background from `scrollpane` and red from `anchorpane`:

[image]

Answer (score 12):

You have to use **css** and like this:

---

```
.scroll-pane{
   -fx-background-color:transparent;
}
```

---

and(cause `ScrollPane` has a `Viewport`)

```
.scroll-pane > .viewport {  //not .scrollpane but .scroll-pane
   -fx-background-color: transparent;
}
```

or

```
.scroll-pane .viewport {
       -fx-background-color: transparent;
}
```

**If** it doesn't work,either you have not defined externall css file well,or you have added some kind of container into the ScrollPane which has also a default background color.

Answer (score 0):

Set an id to your AnchorPane in the fxml and then in your css assign the id to -fx-background-color : transparent.

Hope this works.

if not Please Refer to this question

[JavaFX ScrollPane border and background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17540137/javafx-scrollpane-border-and-background)

Comment: not work,I tried and on scrollpane css 
.scrollpane > .viewport{
       -fx-background-color: transparent;
}

but nothing

Comment: updated the answer with a link please refer to that link