Transparency issue in javaFx
One of the window my program has, is a TextFlow that is filled by an API, it was working fine with the window being semi-transparent but after  some time the amount of information was way beyond the screen height, so when I added a ScrollPane to compensate that, the TextFlow lost its transparency.
This is my current FXML after I tried a bunch of stuff
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.Cursor?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.Pane?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.TextFlow?>

<AnchorPane fx:id="rootPane" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefWidth="333.0" style="-fx-background-color: transparent;" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/22" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="br.com.cpaps.systemmanager.controllers.ramalController">
   <children>
      <Pane layoutX="17.0" layoutY="68.0" prefHeight="32.0" prefWidth="300.0" style="-fx-background-color: black; -fx-border-color: white; -fx-border-width: 0 3 3 3;">
         <children>
            <Label layoutX="110.0" layoutY="-1.0" text="RAMAIS" textFill="WHITE">
               <font>
                  <Font name="JetBrains Mono ExtraBold" size="22.0" />
               </font>
            </Label>
            <Label fx:id="ramalExitButton" layoutX="259.0" layoutY="2.0" onMouseClicked="#close" onMouseEntered="#displayExit" onMouseExited="#hideExit" opacity="0.5" text="[X]" textAlignment="CENTER" textFill="WHITE">
               <font>
                  <Font name="JetBrains Mono ExtraBold" size="15.0" />
               </font>
               <opaqueInsets>
                  <Insets />
               </opaqueInsets>
               <padding>
                  <Insets bottom="2.0" left="2.0" right="2.0" top="2.0" />
               </padding>
               <cursor>
                  <Cursor fx:constant="HAND" />
               </cursor>
            </Label>
         </children>
      </Pane>
      <AnchorPane layoutX="17.0" layoutY="100.0" style="-fx-background-color: transparent" />
      <ScrollPane fitToHeight="true" fitToWidth="true" hbarPolicy="NEVER" layoutX="17.0" layoutY="100.0" maxHeight="600.0" pannable="true" prefWidth="302.0">
        <content>
          <AnchorPane cache="true" maxHeight="600.0" pickOnBounds="false" prefWidth="306.0" style="-fx-background-color: transparent">
               <children>
                  <TextFlow fx:id="ramalTextFlow" maxHeight="600.0" prefWidth="300.0" style="-fx-background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);">
                     <children>
                        <Label opacity="0.5" prefWidth="200.0" text="  NOME" textFill="WHITE" wrapText="true">
                           <padding>
                              <Insets top="5.0" />
                           </padding>
                           <font>
                              <Font name="JetBrains Mono ExtraBold" size="15.0" />
                           </font>
                        </Label>
                        <Label alignment="CENTER" contentDisplay="CENTER" opacity="0.5" prefWidth="60.0" text="NUM." textFill="WHITE" wrapText="true">
                           <padding>
                              <Insets top="5.0" />
                           </padding>
                           <font>
                              <Font name="JetBrains Mono ExtraBold" size="15.0" />
                           </font>
                        </Label>
                     </children>
                     <padding>
                        <Insets bottom="15.0" left="15.0" right="15.0" />
                     </padding>
                  </TextFlow>
               </children>
            </AnchorPane>
        </content>
      </ScrollPane>
   </children>
   <padding>
      <Insets bottom="30.0" />
   </padding>
</AnchorPane>


On the FXML I tried setting the -fx-background-color transparent, rgb with alpha channel, hex and yet nothing worked.
Also tried setting it on the initialize() but still nothing.
And also this is my controller for the FXML
package br.com.cpaps.systemmanager.controllers;

import br.com.cpaps.systemmanager.data.RamaisApi;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Cursor;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.scene.text.TextFlow;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;

public class ramalController {
    @FXML
    private AnchorPane rootPane;

    @FXML
    private Label ramalExitButton;

    @FXML
    private TextFlow ramalTextFlow;


    @FXML
    public void initialize() throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
        // Fetch data from the API
        RamaisApi apiClient = new RamaisApi();
        JsonNode response = apiClient.fetchAllRamals();


        if (response != null) {
            for (JsonNode ramalNode : response) {
                String nome = ramalNode.path("nome").asText();
                String ramal = ramalNode.path("ramal").asText();

                // Create Text nodes for name and number
                Text nameText = new Text(nome);
                nameText.setFont(new Font("JetBrains Mono ExtraBold", 13));
                nameText.setFill(javafx.scene.paint.Color.WHITE);

                Text numberText = new Text(ramal);
                numberText.setFont(new Font("JetBrains Mono ExtraBold", 13));
                numberText.setFill(javafx.scene.paint.Color.WHITE);

                HBox hBox = new HBox();
                hBox.setOpacity(0.8);
                hBox.setSpacing(10);
                hBox.setMaxHeight(200);
                hBox.setId("ramalSet");

                HBox nameBox = new HBox(nameText);
                nameBox.setPrefWidth(200);
                nameBox.setPrefHeight(10);
                nameBox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_LEFT);

                nameText.wrappingWidthProperty().bind(nameBox.widthProperty());

                HBox numberBox = new HBox(numberText);
                numberBox.setPrefWidth(60);
                numberBox.setPrefHeight(10);
                numberBox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_LEFT);

                numberText.wrappingWidthProperty().bind(numberBox.widthProperty());

                hBox.getChildren().addAll(nameBox, numberBox);
                hBox.setOnMouseClicked(event -> {
                    apiClient.pushCall(ramal);
                    close();
                });
                hBox.setOnMouseEntered(event -> {
                    hBox.setOpacity(1);
                    hBox.setCursor(Cursor.HAND);
                });
                hBox.setOnMouseExited(event -> {
                    hBox.setOpacity(0.8);
                    hBox.setCursor(Cursor.HAND);
                });
                ramalTextFlow.getChildren().add(hBox);
            }
        }
    }
    @FXML
    public void close(){
        Stage currentStage = (Stage) rootPane.getScene().getWindow();
        currentStage.close();
    }
    @FXML
    public void displayExit(MouseEvent event){
        ramalExitButton.setOpacity(1);
    }

    @FXML
    public void hideExit(MouseEvent event){
        ramalExitButton.setOpacity(0.5);
    }
}


It seems like the scroll pane itself needs to be transparent? It seems like you could make a minimal compilable example with a ScrollPane and TextFlow to demonstrate the issue.

If I'm not mistaken, the scroll pane itself and its viewport both have non-transparent backgrounds. So do the scroll bars. You'll have to set the backgrounds of these various components. And since some of these components are children of other components, the easiest way to do this is via a separate CSS stylesheet with appropriate selectors. See the JavaFX CSS Reference Guide for the structure of scroll panes and scroll bars and related style classes.

Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40253661/javafx-scrollpane-how-set-transparent-background work?

The default application-wide user agent stylesheet (modena.css) applies backgrounds to many of the built-in controls. Sometimes the background is applied to the control itself, one or more of its child nodes, or all of the above. The JavaFX CSS Reference Guide gives a decent overview of the documented structures of the controls (more specifically, their default skins) as well as what CSS style-classes and pseudo-classes are available. Though it doesn't tell you what the default styles are. For that, your best bet is to study modena.css or use a tool such as Scenic View or the "CSS Analyzer" view of Scene Builder.
From what I can tell, ScrollPane has its own background and that of its viewport set to a non-transparent color. So, it's not that your TextFlow "lost" its transparency, but that one of its ancestor nodes has a non-transparent background. Meaning you are seeing that background instead of what's behind it. You will have to remove these backgrounds if you want the same look as before adding the ScrollPane. Also note that the various components of the ScrollBars also have non-transparent backgrounds. You will probably want to modify those as well.
Example
Since the nodes you want to set the backgrounds of include some children of controls, it would be easiest to do this via a CSS stylesheet instead of via inline styles (whether in code or FXML). Here is an example where:

The ScrollPane and its viewport are made transparent.

The TextFlow and ScrollBars are given a semi-transparent black background. The Text's fill is set to white so the text is still visible.

The arrow buttons and thumb of the ScrollBars are given a slightly less transparent "lighter black" background.

The root of the scene is given a linear gradient to demonstrate the translucence of the TextFlow and the full transparency of the ScrollPane.

The text is set to some simple lorem ipsum text.


import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.scene.text.TextFlow;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Application.launch(Main.class, args);
  }

  @Override
  public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    var text = new Text(LOREM_IPSUM);
    text.getStyleClass().add("text");

    var flow = new TextFlow(text);
    flow.getStyleClass().add("text-flow");

    var scroll = new ScrollPane(flow);
    scroll.setFitToWidth(true);

    var scene = new Scene(new StackPane(scroll), 600, 400);
    scene.getStylesheets().add("data:text/css," + CSS);

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
  }

  private static final String CSS =
      """
      .root {
          -fx-background-color: linear-gradient(to bottom, #09203F, #537895);
      }

      .scroll-pane,
      .scroll-pane .viewport {
          -fx-background-color: transparent;
      }

      .text-flow,
      .scroll-bar {
          -fx-background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
      }

      .scroll-bar .increment-arrow,
      .scroll-bar .decrement-arrow,
      .scroll-bar .thumb {
          -fx-background-color: rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.65);
      }

      .text-flow {
          -fx-padding: 0.7em;
          -fx-font: 11pt "Segoe UI";
      }

      .text-flow .text {
          -fx-fill: white;
      }
      """;

  private static final String LOREM_IPSUM =
      """
      Lorem ipsum odor amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Habitant ullamcorper bibendum habitasse metus ridiculus sociosqu. Diam vulputate enim mi pretium fringilla aliquet. Duis aliquam habitant auctor neque vestibulum suspendisse ridiculus nam inceptos. Est efficitur cubilia semper semper risus. Felis odio morbi per congue maximus commodo diam. Id purus cubilia faucibus per tempor habitasse nostra.

      Morbi donec eleifend semper elementum maximus tincidunt dis eros diam. Nunc potenti ipsum adipiscing, luctus a dignissim luctus. Curae ex ornare lacinia eleifend accumsan tristique neque. Felis hendrerit eu nullam mauris phasellus platea pretium ultrices ad. Nam mauris fusce nulla platea parturient platea. Potenti lobortis accumsan tortor cubilia integer nec. Varius diam laoreet ex consequat magnis congue vivamus. Cras maecenas hendrerit maximus facilisi metus placerat efficitur.

      Vehicula sit facilisis quam malesuada netus tincidunt. Laoreet aliquet senectus leo per elementum rhoncus primis. Sed accumsan mi nunc facilisis nec blandit. Accumsan nostra odio neque feugiat amet fusce. Fusce varius mollis euismod hendrerit nam netus est lacinia libero. Ad sollicitudin varius libero iaculis magnis a ipsum bibendum. Nullam elementum odio torquent fringilla metus fames efficitur sodales laoreet.

      Dapibus iaculis hac vehicula netus fringilla himenaeos torquent? Penatibus imperdiet pellentesque tempor taciti sed etiam nostra. Integer dignissim quis donec convallis cras potenti nam dui. Magna nam netus ipsum at facilisis. Vehicula vehicula platea montes integer blandit habitasse sagittis. Non odio parturient interdum proin bibendum urna id gravida.

      Interdum maecenas volutpat nec lectus justo suscipit, montes iaculis ac. Consequat cubilia lobortis ipsum hendrerit posuere quis enim torquent. Cras duis malesuada viverra malesuada per mauris. Amet vehicula eleifend vulputate sociosqu sollicitudin. Malesuada euismod bibendum ac vehicula non dolor consectetur rutrum iaculis. Montes luctus sagittis aptent pharetra elementum donec. Cubilia iaculis egestas iaculis turpis est lobortis justo tortor. Enim et justo tempus ac laoreet tincidunt. Pellentesque ligula dapibus odio pharetra viverra sapien metus class taciti.

      Montes litora ullamcorper morbi eu suspendisse. Senectus eros sem magnis porta, malesuada lacus dignissim. Euismod adipiscing arcu dignissim vitae ridiculus. Lectus class lacinia ridiculus elementum tempus turpis. Augue vestibulum ante arcu duis conubia torquent fringilla lacinia. Nulla semper dolor interdum nullam nulla elementum ac fusce. Tempor tincidunt viverra venenatis orci, tellus scelerisque pellentesque.

      Tellus dignissim dictum sodales eu augue donec velit condimentum. Ex venenatis nascetur interdum neque cras et neque mollis. Cras mus sociosqu tincidunt aliquet magnis phasellus. Euismod etiam ornare malesuada sed; nunc blandit inceptos euismod. Commodo integer ante eros fermentum iaculis laoreet. Integer torquent congue cubilia suspendisse lectus tristique sodales! Cubilia varius molestie duis aliquet felis convallis quam. Sociosqu consectetur mattis etiam amet volutpat justo. Per penatibus nibh, pharetra nunc consectetur adipiscing. Per pretium fermentum montes phasellus neque commodo senectus?

      Nec faucibus malesuada ultrices condimentum dolor gravida; amet mi. Etiam purus sem ante eget condimentum mauris auctor in. Accumsan auctor sociosqu, nascetur convallis nullam velit lectus congue. Natoque lacus nulla ultrices lacus urna. In hac duis; ad in cras pulvinar hendrerit? Tempus sagittis eros accumsan litora etiam vitae. Faucibus natoque sapien dui a ligula eleifend proin.

      Orci nulla nunc sapien in nisi torquent nullam pellentesque aliquet. Ante praesent tortor per; in quisque et condimentum litora augue. Habitasse eget efficitur, urna molestie primis dictum. Elementum lacus euismod etiam ultricies nulla fermentum quam dictumst! Facilisi pharetra commodo velit placerat sapien ullamcorper nibh volutpat. Mi proin eu conubia dapibus senectus est scelerisque parturient.

      Turpis enim vel, imperdiet phasellus sodales quam nulla. Cras nulla netus ad nibh euismod nascetur quam dolor. Inceptos ad urna ultricies aptent quis dignissim praesent. Netus tortor turpis venenatis sapien, efficitur taciti est adipiscing. Erat ante nisi molestie nam hendrerit augue. Tellus est accumsan nascetur leo litora erat non. Nunc hac ultricies taciti vehicula; taciti class consequat. Maximus suscipit conubia aptent eros dolor.
      """;
}

Couple notes:

The example uses multiline strings (i.e., "text blocks") which requires Java 15+.

To make the example easier to run it uses a multiline string for the CSS stylesheet and adds it to the scene as a data URI. This requires JavaFX 17+. Here is the CSS separately for convenience:
.root {
    -fx-background-color: linear-gradient(to bottom, #09203F, #537895);
}

.scroll-pane,
.scroll-pane .viewport {
    -fx-background-color: transparent;
}

.text-flow,
.scroll-bar {
    -fx-background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.scroll-bar .increment-arrow,
.scroll-bar .decrement-arrow,
.scroll-bar .thumb {
    -fx-background-color: rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.65);
}

.text-flow {
    -fx-padding: 0.7em;
    -fx-font: 11pt "Segoe UI";
}

.text-flow .text {
    -fx-fill: white;
}



